# Application context getting initialized twice

Tags: spring

I'm new to Spring and have inherited some Groovy code that relies heavily on Spring. I'm now trying to figure out why my application context is getting intialized twice, and causing multiple copies of my beans to be created.

I've added a `@Scheduled` task that gets executed with a `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`, and inside the task I'm using the application context's `getBean` static method. In the main program, I'm also using the context to get beans, and I'm finding that the context is getting initialized in both the main program and the scheduled task, which means the task is using a different copy of the bean than the rest of the program.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, never mind. I was creating two different ApplicationContext objects, both loading the same Config. So problem solved.